# Server with 2 NICs / subnets, can't get networks to talk to each other

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

Here is my environment:
I have 2 subnets in my environment:
NetworkA 192.168.10.x is our main network with computers, servers, printers, etc.
NetworkB 10.1.10.y is our facilities network with thermostats, cameras, monitoring devices.

- ServerA: HP DL165 G7, Windows 2008 R2 64bit, domain controller, with DHCP, DNS.  this is on NetworkA
- ServerB: HP DL165 G7, Windows 2008 R2 64bit. It is using both NIC cards.  NIC#1 goes to the networkA.  NIC#2 goes to NetworkB
- Firewall: Juniper Netscreen 5gts.  It is on NetworkA.

I am trying to get the computers on NetworkA to see the items on NetworkB.  many of the items on NetworkB have built-in webserver software.

I'm sure I have to make a static route, but i am not sure where.  On serverA (because it is a DNS server)? Firewall (because it's the gateway)? ServerB (because you can see NIC#1 on it)?

Or i'm barking up the wrong tree.  Can someone point me in the direction to go?

Comment: You need [Routing and Remote Access Services (RRAS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469845.aspx).

Comment: I put RRAS on ServerA?

Comment: Server B. You have a server with more than one NIC plugged into more than one network and that server needs to pass traffic between those networks? That's a router.

Comment: I installed RRAS onto serverB.  I've done a couple of configurations on it but it hasn't worked yet.  I was able to get NetworkB to communicate with NetworkA, but not NetworkA to networkB.  I'm thinking that the firewall (networkA's gateway) needs a static route to ServerB.  am I on the right track?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a router to route traffic between the two subnets.

Usually, you would have a core layer 3 switch (router) that will handle this. You can also use something like RRAS to turn a Windows Server into a router, though it is *far* less common than having a hardware router handle this.

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft terminology, we're dealing with a [Simple routing scenario](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469784.aspx#mainBody), as illustrated below:

[image]

Deploying RRAS for private network routing is relatively simple:

1. Open the RRAS Management Console (`rrasmgmt.msc`)
2. Right-click your RRAS server in the left pane and select Properties
3. Enable it as an **IPv4 Router** with **LAN routing only**
4. In the console, expand **IPv4**, right-click **Static Routes**
5. Create a static route for NetworkA:

   1. Select "New Static Route"
   2. **Interface**: NIC#1 (since this is the interface connected to NetworkA)
   3. **Destination**: 192.168.10.0 (the network adress of NetworkA)
   4. **Network Mask**: 255.255.255.0
   5. **Gateway**: Same as the default gateway on NIC#1
   6. If the RRAS is the only link between the two network segments you don't need to worry about the **Metric** (or the *cost*) of the route.
6. Repeat step 5.1-5.6 for NetworkB
7. Configure the gateways with static routes for the other network, with the RRAS server as gateway

If ServerB *is* the gateway for NetworkB, you just need to add a static route for NetworkB on the Juniper box.

If you only need a select set of clients on NetworkA to access NetworkB, add the static routes on the individual clients instead. You can either do it:

- Manually
- Using DHCP Option 249 (Classless Static Routes)
- [Using Group Policy](https://serverfault.com/a/487244/105072)